# netbeans 12 refuses to run javafx main class

Tags: javafx, netbeans

Yesterday I closed my JavaFX project in Netbeans 12. Today I try to open and run it and get: "Available classes: initializing view, please wait". I'm not the first one with that problem but after several hours of trawling the web, nothing hes been resolved.

Tried the obvious, set project etc., but even "clean and build" brings up the same error. Setting the main class manually under properties also doesn't work. I cannot compile, clean or anything. No errors are showing in the project panel and I've run out of ideas.

The only clue is that the project name is highlighted in bold red, but there are no error messages anywhere, because nothing works.

Anyone please?

Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0
Java: 17; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17+35-2724
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 17+35-2724
System: Linux version 5.4.0-89-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_NZ (nb)

The only difference between yesterday and today is a few (unrelated??) updates.

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) Have you tried cleaning the cache? Go to Help > About, and note the location of the cache directory. Exit from NetBeans. Delete the Cache directory. Restart NetBeans. (2) You may also want to look for errors in the main NetBeans log file. Go to Help > About again, and note the location of the user directory. From there go to the \var\log subdirectory and look in the messages.log file.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, but no go. I have now re-installed Netbeans (12.05), re-installed OpenJDK (17) , re-installed OpenJFX, re-created my JFX library, redone my VM options, created another project, copied the previous source files, refactored etc.

The latest error is now: Warning: java executable not found in JDK. The logfile shows: PlatformComboBoxModel: All platforms filtered out. Adding default platform although it is not accepted by all PlatformFilters. I'll keep trying!

Comment: NetBeans 12.0 is focused on Java 13 & Java 14. See the ["features" notes](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb120/index.html). Should have spotted that before my previous comments. Try upgrading NetBeans to the latest (and check the notes), or downgrading Java.

Comment: (Also, it helps to add relevant new info into the body of the question - e.g. formatted error messages - instead of in comments.)

Comment: The Netbeans version above was my mistake. I installed Netbeans 12.5 (not 12.05). The release notes state that javadoc for Java 18 was added, so I assumed Java 17 was already supported. I'll keep at it and report any successes.

Comment: For such a serious issue there is probably some useful information in the NetBeans log file. Try this: [1] Navigate to **View > IDE Log** which will show the most recent messages from the log in the **Output** window. [2] Now try to open your project again. [3] Are any messages being written to the log? If so, update your question with the messages that were logged by attempting to open the project. Be sure to include the stack traces if there are any.

Comment: I did that, but didn't spot any clues. I have now transferred all code to a Maven project and I am up and running again. I did notice that the Netbeans terminal puts out a message relating to a terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System. I'll report that to the maintainers of org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager  (as suggested in the message). I'm guessing it is not related to my original problem though.